# Format JSONB column by taking the text value from same jsonb coulmn

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

`CREATE TABLE test(id serial, data jsonb); INSERT INTO test(data) values ('dummydata-got-uploaded');`

I need to correct the jsonb column value with below query.

`update test set data={"addDet": data }::jsonb where id =1;`
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: update test set data={"addDet": data...

Expected:

### `id | data`

`1  | {"addDet": 'dummydata-got-uploaded' }`
`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to have a look at `json_build_object` function

```
update test set data=json_build_object('addDet', data )::jsonb where id =1;
```